# Flutter: How to make first launch app tour guide?

Tags: widget, flutter, launch

How to show an app tour guide/intro on the first launch?

What widget should I use and how to detect the first launch?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/feature_discovery

Answer (score 4):

This feature is currently not implemented yet.

You can follow this issue to see Flutter's progress on the topic: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/4296

Or you can try to make it yourself and submit a pull request.